# Unrecognized Deep Link Fallback not working in simulator

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm having trouble triggering my unrecognized action fallback intent. When I start the app with an unrecognized implicit action the default welcome intent is triggered. I followed the instructions on this page https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/define-actions. The fallback intent has an input context of google_assistant_welcome, and the action name is deeplink.unknown. The default welcome intent has no contexts, and has GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME in it's events section. What am I doing wrong?

[image: default welcome intent]
[image: deep-link fallback]
[image: integrations]

Comment: Which command do you use to try to trigger your deep link intent . If I remember correctly, to trigger a Deep Link, you need to say 'Talk to <my app> about **something**'

Comment: In addition to @RémiC.'s excellent question, can you also update your question to show us screen shots of the intents in question? Can you also show us the configuration for the Integration page when you click on the Assistant?

Comment: @RémiC. I'm trying to trigger a fallback intent for deep links, so 'Talk to <my app> about airplanes'. The phase after about can be anything that doesn't match any of my intents, right?

When I say airplanes, as an example, it responds with the welcome intent response, instead of the deep link fallback response.

Comment: As I've never used Deep Link, I'm not really sure... Do you have your Deep Link fallback coded in your webhook ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was (in addition to all your steps): add a training phrase of literally `"any phrase"` and mark the entire phrase as `@sys.any`.

[image]

Those are the steps outlines in Google's [Actions on Google codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/#3) (see "Define a custom fallback intent") to add a fallback for an unrecognized deeplink.

Comment: Confusingly, that step isn't mentioned under "Handling unrecognized Actions when users invoke your Action" in the _Action on Google_ docs your provided. Not sure if that section is describing something slightly different or...